# “A threat to us people” or “a threat to we people”?

Tags: pronouns, prepositional-phrases, grammatical-case

Which of these is correct:

1. Global warming is a great threat to **us** people.
2. Global warming is a great threat to **we** people.

Looking on the web, usage seems divided. Compare:

1. > I believe that it is in our best interest that Congress recognize us and come here to **us people** and ask us — not tell us, what we need to do in order to protect ourselves and our children. — [To Amend the Alaska Native Claims Settlement Act](https://books.google.com/books?id=oInkJVshUH0C&pg=PA606&dq=%22to%20us%20people%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_7Lv8waX3AhWrjIkEHWhsB7oQ6AF6BAgJEAM)
2. > It seems to **we people** who live in this area that it is time for the Federal and State Governments to start some positive flood control action. — [Ohio Storm Damage Inspection](https://books.google.com/books?id=a30qAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA259&dq=%22to%20we%20people%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN_f-9waX3AhWJjokEHcJvC5YQ6AF6BAgMEAM)

What's the rule?

Comment: Compare: "Global warming is a great threat to **us people.** But as to **you robots,** you all just need batteries and some oil."

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Global warming is a great threat to **us** people.
> 2. Global warming is a great threat to **we** people.

The first version (#1) is grammatical in today's standard English.

The second version (#2) seems to be ungrammatical (that is, unacceptable), because the word "we" is in nominative case instead of the expected accusative case. The rest of this post will be about version #1.

In your version #1, the word "us" is a **personal determinative.**

1. *Global warming is a great threat to* [***us*** *people*].

The expression inside the brackets is a noun phrase (NP). The head of that NP is the noun "people". The word "us" is the determiner of that NP.

Here are some similar examples that use personal determinatives, from *CGEL* page 374:

- [5.i] [***We*** *supporters of a federal Europe] will eventually win the argument.*
- [5.ii] [***You*** *students] should form a society.*

In those examples, the "We" and "You" are personal determinatives functioning as determiners (though they are in nominative case instead of accusative case that is in your example). Those determinatives are functioning as determiners within the subject NPs.

*CGEL* says on page 374:

- *It should be noted that the personal determinatives are exactly parallel to other definite determiners such as the demonstratives and the definite article in, for example, permitting the universal quantifier as predeterminer.*

Note that *CGEL* is the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL). Related info is in *CGEL*, "***7.2 The personal determinatives*** **we** ***and*** **you**", page 374.

Comment: Sssh don't tell anyone but determinatives don't exist: they are all pronouns...  :)

Comment: Actually, it's #1 that is strictly speaking ungrammatical.

Comment: @BillJ The only way I could see someone making that claim is hypercorrection—knowing that “us people do something” is supposed to be wrong but not quite figuring out why.

Answer (score 1):

***Global warming is a great threat to us people*** is correct; however, as Jason said, you could go without using the word "people."

The reason for this is because "US" is the object of the sentence, and therefore you need an objective case pronoun (ex: me, you, him/her/it, us, you, them). "We" is used for the nominative case (or when it is the subject of a sentence).

Answer (score 0):

*Us* is the correct pronoun to follow the preposition *to*. However, a pronoun is not needed. "***Global warming is a great threat to people***," works just fine.

Answer (score -2):

"Global warming is a great threat to us people." is more grammatically correct. However, this doesn't mean it *is* grammatically correct.

Think about the sentence without the word "people."

> Global warming is a great threat to us.
>
> Global warming is a great threat to we.

It's obvious which one sounds strange.

Omitting the word before "people" might be a better choice.

Comment: That was my reaction, unless (as in the comments at top) you want to explicitly distinguish the speaker from a non-person being spoken to. Or perhaps "our people" (specifying those of our culture or country or whatever) was intended.

Answer (score -2):

I would say that "Global warming is a great threat to us people" because it is easy to understand and quite common usage. However you could say the other version to give a more 'dramatic' meaning I suppose. Hope this helps.