# Is it grammatically correct to use "we" or "us" as well as the name of a group? e.g. "A meeting of we employees went very well."

Tags: word-usage, subjects, objects

Is "we + [name of group]" a grammatically correct construction?

Example:
"A meeting of we employees went very well."

Also, what about this:
"They gave donuts to us employees at the meeting."

Comment: As Araucaria mentions in answers below, the first example as well as the second should have _us employees_ rather than _we_, as in both cases the phrase serves as the object of a preposition.

Comment: Or just use _we_ as the subject of _had_ and _employees_ as the object of the preposition. _We had an employees meeting that went very well._ That identifies the speaker(s) as employees without having to diddle pronouns.

Comment: Compare [“A threat to us people” or “a threat to we people”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/177979/a-threat-to-us-people-or-a-threat-to-we-people)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly grammatical:

> We employees had a good meeting.

In English, nouns usually have some kind of determiner which precedes them. Determiners are words such as *a, the, his, this, some, both, one, either, no* and so forth.

You will notice that *the* and *a* are unusual determiners. The reason why is that most other words that are determiners can also be used like pronouns without a following noun:

- Can I have some bread?
- Can I have some?

or

- Give me that book!
- Give me that!

or

- I can't give you either option.
- I can't give you either.

It is not altogether surprising then, that there are likewise some words which are pronouns that we can also use as determiners! Specifically, the pronouns *you* *we* and *us* are quite often used as determiners with a following noun:

- You bastards!
- ...We few, we happy few, we band of brothers. (Shakespeare: King Henry V)
- much cleverer than us mere mortals.

In informal speech we also hear phrases such as:

- them idiots over there.

Interestingly, the fact that we use pronouns as determiners and determiners as pronouns has led some grammarians to argue either that all pronouns are determiners - or that all determiners are pronouns. In either case, if it's good enough for Shakespeare ...

I would tend to counsel that if the noun is the subject of the sentence use *we X*. If it isn't, use *us X*. However, both are seen in either position.

One last thing. Using pronouns as determiners like this is relatively unusual, and so gives quite a literary or at times informal flavour to your writing. I wouldn't use this in a formal report, for example!

*Hope this is helpful!*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is.

It's how a speaker both names a group and includes themself as a member of that group.

Comment: But generally should match the case, such that the first example ought to be "of us employees".

Comment: @guifa Us teachers don't agree ;)

Comment: @guifa We do really! Kinda

Comment: @araucaria I did say generally ;) I personally in speech use *us* almost exclusively, but while *we* there doesn't cause me to bat an eye while taking to someone, *we* in an object case sounds way weird.

Comment: @guifa In formal speech, it should match the case. In informal speech, native speakers have a strong tendency to switch to the accusative case ("me" instead of "I", "us" instead of "we") in cases where the pronoun doesn't immediately precede a verb, so using "us" exclusively is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

It is not grammatically correct. "We employees" is being used as the object of the preposition "of." As such, it is incorrect - "we" is the nominative form of the pronoun, and "us" is the objective form (as in "object of a preposition.)  Take out the word "employees," and you will see that "us" even sounds correct because it is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).