# Should it be "we animals" or "us animals"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, reflexives

In the [serialization of my book](https://ramblingnotesofageezer.substack.com/p/taterskin-and-the-eco-defenders-book-610), I have this passage:

> Brief introductions were made, although when Albert tried to tell them the names of we animals, they waved him off.

But now I'm wondering whether "we animals" is correct, or should it be "us animals"?

Comment: tell them the name of us animals, because of the the of. But: We animals are meaner than rattlesnakes. For me, the "of" triggers the objective case, as it were.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of ["we/us people"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/177979/191178), which I think we should reopen.

Comment: 'Of us animals' is the grammatically correct choice. Butt it sounds at best clumsy, and grammaticality isn't the sole measure of acceptability. // Does 'them / ... they' really fit after 'Brief introductions were made'? I'm trying to think of a previous sentence that works here.

Comment: "We, the animals of Arcadia, determined that..." are the subjects, and "...given to us, the animals of Arcadia" are the objects.

Comment: If the reader knows that 'we' are animals, why not just 'our names'?

Comment: @KateBunting. Good point; maybe I should have provided more context, as Albert is a human, and the other humans he's talking to do not believe the animals accompanying him can understand human speech.

Comment: Strictly speaking nominative "we" is correct, but accusative "us" is commonly found in colloquial and dialectal varieties.

Comment: But if Albert is human, he wouldn't talk about 'we animals' anyway!

Comment: @KateBunting. Taterskin the Labrador Retriever is speaking. The story is told in "first Canine"